# Reading the contents of a .bkf file using a non-Microsoft OS

Tags: linux, mac, backup, bkf

I have a .bkf backup file, created by the Backup utility that Microsoft provides with Windows XP.  Is there a way to read the contents of the file using a non-Microsoft OS, preferably Mac OS X or Linux?

Answer (score 6):

I use and love [`mtftar`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/mtftar/). It converts the `.bkf` stream written by `ntbackup` (the Windows Backup utility in XP) to a simple `tar` backup, which is easy to manipulate. The program compiles on both Linux and OS X (as long as the Developer Tools/XCode are installed).